# How to return the numerical position of a piece of data within a dataset?

Tags: javascript, database, d3.js

Firstly sorry for how stupid I'm sure this question is.

I'm working through early examples in the 'Interactive Data Visualization for the Web' by Scott Murray.

One of the exercises is simply showing how d3 can create paragraphs of text based on datapoints within a dataset.

I'm trying to work out how to return the numerical position of a datapoint within a dataset to integrate within that paragraph.

For example, for the dataset [5, 10, 15], I'm looking for the result of three paragraphs reading:

The value of the datapoint 1 is 5.

The value of the datapoint 2 is 10.

The value of the datapoint 3 is 15.

How do I express the 1, 2, 3 in code?

```
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];

d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text(function(d) { return "The value of datapoint " + **what would I write here to return 1, 2, 3 etc. depending on the position of each datapoint within the dataset** "is " + d; });
```

Comment: That is called **index** not **value** and arrays have the `.indexOf(...)` function that you can use for that. Here is an example: `dataset.indexOf(d)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `function(d)` with `function(d, i)` in the `text` function, the `i` is the index of the item. You can do this for `.attr`, `.style`, etc.

So your code would look like:

```
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];

d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("p")
.text(function(d, i) { return "The value of datapoint " + i + " is " + d; })
```